# How to decrement an array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, char, decrement

This is my code to start.

```
static char[] a1 = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'};
static char[] a2 = {'a', 'c', 'd', 'c'};

        for (int i = 1; i <= 5 ; i++) {

            if( a1[i] == a2[i] ){
                sop(a2[i] + "");
            }else{

                if( a1[i] > a2[i] ){
                    sop("");
                }else if( a1[i] < a2[i] ){
                    sop("-");
                    a2[i] = a2[i-1];
                }

            }
        }
```

I would like to know how do you decrement the line `a2[i] = a2[i-1]`. Did I do it right?

In the end, I'm trying to align `a1` and `a2`. So I could get the output:

```
ABCDE
A-CD-C
```

Note: `sop = System.out.print`

Comment: Whats your first language? What i can understand, you are only changing 1 spot in the array, do you want to change all? you will need a second for, to change the other values.

Comment: @RicardoOrtegaMagaña Do you mean the programming language? I'm trying to decrement the array of a2

Comment: For you example, please post an output you want to get.  If arrays themselves are supposed to change, please show us how.

Comment: @Lord Rixuel Sorry, but "decrement the array" is not clear.

Comment: @PM77-1 im comparing a1 and a2. First, I get 'a' and 'a', then i get 'b' and 'c'. After, I get 'c' and 'd', But since 'b' and 'c' are not equal, i don't want the value 'c' of a2 move to 'd' so I could get 'c' and 'c' next instead of 'c' and 'd'.

Comment: What are the exact rules for this *alignment*.

Comment: If array elements don not match, why does it matter if one is more or less than another?

Answer (score 0):

If I get your thinking, in using the decrement you were maybe trying to decrement the usage of the index for just the second array? If so, it doesn't work that way. Besides there are problems such as the array addressing (Java indexes Array elements from position 0, not position 1.

Anyway, for your problem statement, you could try:

```
static char[] a1 = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'};
static char[] a2 = {'a', 'c', 'd', 'c'};

for(int k=0;k<a1.length;k++)
    System.out.print(a1[k]);
System.out.println();

for (int i = 0, j=0 ; i<a1.length && j<a2.length ; i++, j++)
{
    if( a1[i] == a2[j] )
        System.out.print(a2[j]);
    else if( a1[i] < a2[j] )
    {
        System.out.print("-");
        j--;
    }

}
```